# Node JS serialport@6.0.0 Opening port and closing it automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino, arduino-uno, node-serialport

I'm using Node JS `SerialPort@6.0.0` Package for connecting to computer ports.

I wrote this code to get the `arduino-uno` data:

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const port = new SerialPort('COM4',{
    baudRate: 9600
});

port.on('open', function(){
    console.log("port open");
    port.on('data', function(data){
        console.log("Data:" + data);
    })
})
```

When it starts it automatically stops in sequence. I already used a err handler but no error was shown. And when im using `serialport@4.0.0` it works flawless.

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKCgZ.png)